# Stagger (transition-delay) children to an element with ng-show

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate

I'm creating a sitemap in a custom CMS powered by Angular.

I hide the lower levels of pages and toggle their visibility with a button. I add `ng-animate` to animate the "opening" of the lower levels of the sitemap.

This works fine for the `<ul>`, but I would rather have its child `<li>` enter with a longer `transition-delay` for every item for a nice waterfall effect and this is where I get stuck.

At first I figured simply adding a `transition-delay` to the `<li>` would be sufficient, but for whatever reason I'm even unable to add a regular `transition` to the `<li>`. I read about the `-stagger` class, but it never gets applied.

### Markup:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="page in data"
      ng-class="{'children-visible': isVisible}"
      ng-init="isVisible = false">
    
    <a href="#">{{page.pagename}}</a>

    <button ng-if="page.sub"
            ng-click="$parent.isVisible = !isVisible">
    </button>

    <ul ng-if="page.sub"
        ng-show="isVisible"
        ng-animate="'animate'">

      <li ng-repeat="page in page.sub">
        <a href="#">{{page.pagename}}</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </li>
</ul>
```

Here's a picture of the markup if it helps you, er, picture it:

[image: Image of rendered markup for the sitemap]

If relevant, I use version 1.2.16 of both `angular.js` and `angular-animate.js`.

**So, in short:** How do I add a stagger/transition delay to children of an element with `ng-show`?